# DotNetNuke Skinning

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skins

I was reading this tutorial from the DNN website
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/2675/DotNetNuke-Skinning-101-Part-2.aspx

I found the tutorial to be very useful, however there was an issue when I tried to apply the CSS style. For example after adding the content pane in the initial index.html I have no idea where to place the CSS. If I add it to the head section then the parser will remove it. 
Where could I add or reference the css file on for the skin? 
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a DNN specialist, but:

A skin normally contains a stylesheet file called "skin.css" in the skins\skin-name folder.

The reference to this stylesheet is provided for you by the DNN framework.

To reference multiple CSS files, or to add css files with different names, you normally @import them from the skin.css file.

Comment: +1 Yep, that's exactly right. All you need to do is place a skin.css file in the skin directory and DNN will load it.

Comment: Great. it works !!! I was using the css with another name "style.css" instead of skin.css.
thank you very much.