# DotNetNuke Skinning: How do I use\add skin.css?

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skinning

I'm just getting started DNN skinning and am confused by how skin.css works.  I'm using the "legacy" skinning method, so my skin folder has SkinName.htm file in it, which I get DNN to parse each time I change it. Now I want to add some css...

According to this: (and various other references I've come across)

[DotNetNuke Skinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237709/dotnetnuke-skinning)

I should just need to add a skin.css file in my skin folder and the DNN framework should automatically add a reference to it.

But I've added a skin.css, containing the following:

```
.Head
{
    color: Green;
}
```

which definitely doesn't make it to my final page; checked with firebug. Nothing like color: Green is being applied to my elements with class="Head"

Anybody have any suggestions on why my skin.css might be ignored? Does the current DNN version still work in this way? Anything obvious I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a skin.css file in your skinning directory the reference will be automatically added.

However, when developing a skin, if you first click "Parse Skin Package" when there is no skin.css file in the directory, it will be ignored after it is created.  The easiest solution is to copy all your skin files to a new skin directory and re-parse the skin package.